# Swapping Next.js index files at build time

Tags: npm, next.js, npm-scripts

I have a Next.js project that runs two different versions depending on which version of `index.js` is in the root folder on build.

Instead of swapping them via the OS before build, is there some pre-processor than can pick the right one and do it for me?  I think of having one `index.js` file in a folder called `foo` and the other in a folder called `bar,` and I can type something like `npm run build bar` and it will build using the `index.js` file in the bar folder.  Or similar.

It seems this could be done with Webpack, and having two different builds in `package.json.`